# 18.04: Uninstall Vivado 2019.1

Tags: apt, software-uninstall, xilinx

I've tried to use the command "sudo ./xsetup -Uninstall" to remove [Vivado](https://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/vivado.html), but I get the message "sudo: ./xsetup: command not found".

Comment: Exactly how did you install vivado 2019.1? A link to the instructions that you followed would be very helpful.

Comment: I downloaded the Ise Webpack from Xilinx site and executed it. https://www.xilinx.com/support/download.html

Answer (score 0):

[xsetup](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_xrandr_changes_persistently) is not the Ubuntu command to use to uninstall a package, but instead is in this case a [script for installation of Vivado only](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xilinx_Vivado#Vivado_and_SDK).

First, confirm the exact package name by reviewing what's installed with `dpkg --list` .

Then, do `sudo apt remove “package-name”` or  `sudo apt purge “package-name”`. The latter removes any personalizations.

`sudo apt autoremove` if run subsequently removes dependencies.

You *may* also be able to use a package manager, such as [Synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto), to remove and purge.

Comment: [dpkg --list | grep vivado] gets no return

Comment: Then search more broadly with the Mk. I eyeball and `dpkg --list`